# Display all pages under categories in PHP with joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables. The first one, pages, contains a foreign key category_id and the other table, categories, contains an id and a title field.

Here is my sql query :

```
SELECT categories.title as titleCategory, pages.title as titlePage FROM categories INNER JOIN pages ON pages.category_id = categories.id ORDER BY categories.title
```

What is want is to display the pages and categories like this :

```
category 1
    page 1
    page 2

category 2
    page 1

etc...
```

Is there a way to do that using a foreach or do I have to use 2 queries?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming PHP, but the logic shoudl work in any language.

```
$cur_cat = null;
foreach($results as $result){
    if($cur_cat != $result['titleCategory']){
        echo $result['titleCategory'];
    }
    $cur_cat = $result['titleCategory'];
    echo $result['titlePage'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a check in the single foreach loop.

```
$currentCategory = null;
foreach( $results as $result ) {
     if( $currentCategory != $result['titleCategory'] ) {
          $currentCategory = $result['titleCategory'];
          echo $result['titleCategory'];
     }
     echo $result['titlePage'];
}
```

This will only print out the title if it has changed. You already have the, ordered by categoryTitle so if the category doesn't change it will only print the pageTitle.

Comment: Much thanks to you too, your solution works as well!